# How do I store a value in LLVM?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, code-generation, llvm, llvm-py

I am using LLVM's [Python bindings](http://www.llvmpy.org/llvmpy-doc/0.11.2/index.html) - and, so far, I've been able to generate `Constant` values using LLVM. However, I am confused as to how to store them within an address.

This is probably a very basic question - how do I store a constant in memory? How do I later access that memory location for that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, storing values to an address is done via a [store](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#store-instruction) instruction ([builder.store](http://www.llvmpy.org/llvmpy-doc/0.11.2/doc/llvm.core.Builder.html#store-self-value-ptr)) and accessing a value within an address is done via a [load](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#load-instruction) instruction ([builder.load](http://www.llvmpy.org/llvmpy-doc/0.11.2/doc/llvm.core.Builder.html#load-self-ptr-name)). It doesn't matter if the argument to the store instruction is a constant or not.

If you're referring to constant [GlobalVariable](http://www.llvmpy.org/llvmpy-doc/0.11.2/doc/llvm.core.GlobalVariable.html)s, however, be aware they are already stored in an address when you create them.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense - thank you. I will edit the title to be a bit more accurate.